# What is this icon of a controller with an upward arrow trying to indicate?

Tags: controllers, detroit-become-human

I'm playing "Detroit: Become Human" on PC via Steam. I've hooked up a Playstation controller since the keyboard+mouse controls are so strangely nonstandard.

The game shows me prompts of what buttons/combos to select to do different actions, but there's one I just can't figure out what it's trying to tell me to do:

[image: Screenshot of button prompt]

I don't understand what the icon on the left is trying to tell me to do. I'm holding down the L2 key which is the icon on the right (hence why it's colored blue), but I haven't been able to figure out what I'm supposed to do in addition.

For further context, I'm currently playing as 'Kara' and am cleaning Todd's house. This sequence of actions is when I'm attempting to "ventilate" the rooms; if I manage to figure out how to activate it, Kara will open the window.

Here's the full view of the current scene:

[image: Current scene]

Actions I've attempted in order to satisfy the prompt:

- physically moving the controller upwards
- swiping upwards on the touchpad
- moving both joysticks upwards
- pressing 'up' on the D-Pad

What action should I be doing when I see this icon that looks like a controller with an upwards arrow?

Comment: Which dualshock controller version is it?

Comment: It's a dualshock 4 controller. I'll try rotating it to be perpendicular.

Comment: Reading some posts on other sites, people have complained at the motion controls, which is what I assume that icon is telling you to do (physically lift the controller upward and I assume you also need to hold L2 while doing that).  I read that holding the controller perpendicular to the floor might help.  I'm also wondering if using a controller on PC supports the motions.

Comment: I can confirm, on PS4 you need to lift the controller while pressing L2. But I've never played it on PC.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to the comments/hints from Timmy Jim and Pinckerman, I've managed to figure out what is going on.

This icon means **lift the controller**, and apparently, this works on the PS4. This does *not* work on PC.

On PC, what you need to do is **rotate the controller 90 degrees** so that it is perpendicular to the floor. If you're holding the controller straight in front of you, rotate your wrists so that the front of the controller is facing your chest. This needs to be a **sharp/abrupt action**, so no gentle rotation.

Note that there's a similar icon with a downward arrow: this means lower the controller, and similarly you need to rotate the controller -90 degrees so it's  perpendicular. (Basically, the opposite motion from the rotate upward; you'll end up with the front of the controller facing away from you.)